# Drawing letters in excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

Is there a plugin that helps generate letters (A-Z) in excel as seen below? Or can we write some sort of VBA script to do this?

[image]

Comment: It isn't completely clear what you are asking for. You seem to want some sort of word-art obtained by coloring cells. There is no add-in that I know of which would do that (and anyway, asking for external resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow). You could clearly write a VBA macro to do that. Depending on what you are trying to do it wouldn't be particularly hard.

Comment: re: '*can **we** write some sort of VBA script to do this*' - Well, *I* can; I'm not sure about you since no code was in your question.

Comment: The easiest way would be to find an open-source dot matrix font of the type that is used in low-resolution LED displays. You should be able to find a file that e.g. contains a 16x12 0-1 valued matrix for each letter on the alphabet. Once you read them into VBA -- push them to Excel ranges (possibly as literal 0s and 1s) and let conditional formatting do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stackoverflow is not a code-for-me service**. Anyhow, the task looked interesting, and I have decided to code something about it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteLetterA()

    Dim varLetterA(8)       As Variant
    Dim lngColCounter       As Long
    Dim lngRowCounter       As Long
    Dim blnReverse          As Boolean
    Dim rngCell             As Range

    blnReverse = True

    varLetterA(0) = Array(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
    varLetterA(1) = Array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
    varLetterA(2) = Array(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    varLetterA(3) = Array(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
    varLetterA(4) = Array(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
    varLetterA(5) = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    varLetterA(6) = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    varLetterA(7) = Array(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
    varLetterA(8) = Array(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)

    Cells(1, 1).Select

    For lngRowCounter = 0 To UBound(varLetterA)
        For lngColCounter = 0 To UBound(varLetterA(lngRowCounter))
            Set rngCell = Cells(lngRowCounter + 1, lngColCounter + 1)
            If varLetterA(lngRowCounter)(lngColCounter) Then
                rngCell.Interior.Color = IIf(blnReverse, vbBlack, vbWhite)
            Else
                rngCell.Interior.Color = IIf(blnReverse, vbWhite, vbBlack)
            End If
        Next lngColCounter
    Next lngRowCounter

End Sub

'   Points for improvement  - varLetterA in a separate class
'   Refer to the sheet, do not assume it
'   Pass the first cell as a reference
```

This is what you get:

`blnReverse = False`

[image]

`blnReverse = True`

[image]

Take a look at the points for improvement - they can be useful, if you decide to build the rest of the alphabet. Good luck.

Comment: "Stackoverflow is not a code-for-me service. Anyhow, the task looked interesting, and I have decided to code something about it" -- I have felt the same way more than once. The `blnReverse` parameter is a good idea. +1

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman - the `blnReverse` appeared, because I have forgotten what was the `0` and `1` in the `varLetterA` and I thought it would be easier this way :)